# SQL Query to apply join on basis of case Condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a requirement where I need to fetch the Dimension Key of Region table on basis of the following preference.

1. Fetch dimension key on basis of Zipcode of Physical address(PA)
2. If the first condition is not satisfied that fetch dimension key on basis of the Zip Code of the Mailing address
3. If the second condition is also not satisfied than fetch the dimension key on basis of the Parish Code of Physical address
4. Else fetch dimension key on basis of parish Code of Mailing address.

I am trying to use the below query but is giving multiple records since all left joins are getting evaluated. I want that it should not go on the second condition if the first condition is satisfied.

```
    select REGION_DIM_SK, CASE_NUM
    from (
        select distinct COALESCE(RDIM.REGION_DIM_SK, RDIM1.REGION_DIM_SK, RDIM2.REGION_DIM_SK, RDIM3.REGION_DIM_SK) AS REGION_DIM_SK
            , DC.CASE_NUM, ADDR_TYPE_CD
        FROM rpt_dm_ee_intg.CASE_PERSON_ADDRESS  dc
        left join  rpt_dm_ee_prsnt.REGION_DIM RDIM on dc.ZIP_CODE = RDIM.ZIP_CODE and RDIM.REGION_EFF_END_DT IS NULL and  dc.addr_type_cd='PA' AND dc.EFF_END_DT IS NULL 
        left join rpt_dm_ee_prsnt.REGION_DIM RDIM1 ON dc.ZIP_CODE = RDIM1.ZIP_CODE AND RDIM1.REGION_EFF_END_DT IS NULL AND dc.addr_type_cd='MA' AND DC.EFF_END_DT IS NULL 
        left join (
            select PARISH_CD, min(REGION_DIM_SK) as REGION_DIM_SK
            from  rpt_dm_ee_prsnt.REGION_DIM
            where REGION_EFF_END_DT is null
            group by PARISH_CD
        ) RDIM2 ON dc.addr_type_cd='PA' and dc.PARISH_CD = RDIM2.PARISH_CD AND DC.EFF_END_DT IS NULL
        left join (
            select PARISH_CD, min(REGION_DIM_SK) as REGION_DIM_SK
            from rpt_dm_ee_prsnt.REGION_DIM
            where REGION_EFF_END_DT is null
            group by PARISH_CD
        ) RDIM3 ON dc.addr_type_cd='MA' and dc.PARISH_CD = RDIM3.PARISH_CD AND DC.EFF_END_DT IS NULL
    ) A
    where REGION_DIM_SK is not null
) RD on RD.case_num = rpt_dm_ee_intg.CASE_PERSON_ELIGIBILITY.CASE_NUM
```

Comment: Your query isn't complete... there is (I guess) a missing select at the start.

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple `left join`s.  Your query is rather hard to follow -- it has other tables and references not described in the problem.

But the idea is:

```
select t.*,
       coalesce(rpa.dim_key, rm.dim_key, rpap.dim_key, rmp.dim_key) as dim_key
from t left join
     dim_region rpa
     on t.physical_address_zipcode = rpa.zipcode left join
     dim_region rm
     on t.mailing_address_zipcode = rm.zipcode and
        rpa.zipcode is null left join
     dim_region rpap
     on t.physical_addresss_parishcode = rpap.parishcode and
        rm.zipcode is null left join
     dim_region rmp
     on t.physical_addresss_parishcode = rmp.parishcode and
        rpap.zipcode is null
```

Answer (score -1):

The trick is to put the conditions in `CASE WHEN`:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM table1 a
JOIN table2 b
    ON CASE 
       WHEN a.code is not null and a.code = b.code THEN 1
       WHEN a.type = b.type THEN 1
       ELSE 0
   END = 1
```

For your example you can reduce the code to just two joins, it can't be done in one as you are joining two different tables.

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN RDIM.addres IS NULL THEN RDIM2.addres ELSE RDIM.addres
FROM rpt_dm_ee_intg.CASE_PERSON_ADDRESS dc
LEFT JOIN rpt_dm_ee_prsnt.REGION_DIM RDIM ON CASE
        WHEN (dc.ZIP_CODE = RDIM.ZIP_CODE
           AND RDIM.REGION_EFF_END_DT IS NULL
           AND dc.addr_type_cd='PA'
           AND dc.EFF_END_DT IS NULL) THEN 1
        WHEN (dc.ZIP_CODE = RDIM1.ZIP_CODE
           AND RDIM1.REGION_EFF_END_DT IS NULL
           AND dc.addr_type_cd='MA'
           AND DC.EFF_END_DT IS NULL) THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END = 1
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT PARISH_CD,
          min(REGION_DIM_SK) AS REGION_DIM_SK
   FROM rpt_dm_ee_prsnt.REGION_DIM
   WHERE REGION_EFF_END_DT IS NULL
   GROUP BY PARISH_CD) RDIM2 ON CASE
        WHEN (dc.addr_type_cd='PA'
              AND dc.PARISH_CD = RDIM2.PARISH_CD
              AND DC.EFF_END_DT IS NULL
              AND RDIM.ZIP_CODE IS NULL) THEN 1
        WHEN (dc.addr_type_cd='MA'
              AND dc.PARISH_CD = RDIM3.PARISH_CD
              AND DC.EFF_END_DT IS NULL
              AND RDIM.ZIP_CODE IS NULL) THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END = 1
```

**edit**
If you don't want to have nulls from `RDIM2` table if `RDIM1` zip code is present the logic could be easily extended to support that. You just need to add `AND RDIM.ZIP_CODE IS NULL` to `CASE WHEN` conditions.

Comment: this will work fine if any case has just physical or mailing address in my case for every row both physical and mailing address are present so this condition is showing record for both address ideally it should only for physical address.

Comment: The logic could be easily extended. If you don't want to have nulls from RDIM2 table if RDIM1 zip code is present the logic could be easily extended to support that. You just need to add AND RDIM.ZIP_CODE IS NULL to CASE WHEN conditions.